# LinqToXML: Getting elements with given value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml-file:

```
<objects>
  <object> 
    <value>test</value>
  </object>
  <object> 
    <value>foo</value>
  </object>
  <object> 
    <value>bar</value>
  </object>      
</objects>
```

Now, I want to query this xml, and retrieve all the object-elements where the text in the value-element = "foo"

Is there a easy way of doing this?

I have tried something like this:

```
var objects = from e in xml.Elements("value")
              where e.Value.Equals("foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
              select e.parent;
```

That does not work..

Comment: Can you define "does not work?"

Does it cause a compiler error? Does it return a set, empty or otherwise?

Comment: "does not work" as in "Enumeration yielded no results".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
xml.Descendants("value")
```

xml.Elements() just returns child elements... if xml is your root XDocument, it wouldn't return anything.

Comment: Yes, Descendants and a trimming of the value solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use *xml.Descendants* assuming you are querying from the document root.  Also, I'd prefer using *string.Equals* over the *Equals* method called off the string returned by the *Value* property of the element (only as a matter of preference.)  For example:

```
var objects = from e in xml.Descendants("value")
                where string.Equals(e.Value, 
                                    "foo", 
                                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                select e.Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var objects = from e in xml.Descendants("object").Elements("value")
                          where e.Value.Equals("foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                          select e.Parent;
```